# Mostrar datos de un Procedimiento almacenado de SQL Server 2008 en PHP

Tags: php, aplicación-web, chart.js, sql-server-2008

Buenas tardes a todos,

necesito hacer 3 gráficos con datos de una base de datos SQL Server 2008, estos datos se sustraen de 3 procedimientos almacenados respectivamente y como la solución es solo una pagina con los 3 gráficos unidos en 1 grande, decidí utilizar php + xampp + chartjs.

Dentro de estos requerimientos, también necesito que la pagina web este constantemente refrescando los datos ya que se actualizan durante todo el día, entonces aquí me surgieron algunas dudas:

1. ¿Para obtener los datos que devuelve un SP de sql server y capturarlos en php, necesito alguna librería o algo adicional?
2. ¿Es posible por ejemplo traer la información de SQL Server, transformarlos en un JSON por ejemplo y luego leerlos por chartjs?, si es así, ¿Cómo podría ser?.
3. ¿Qué otra cosa adicional, librería, driver, etc, necesito para conectar SQL Server con xampp y respectivamente PHP?.

No sé si otra tecnología web como por ejemplo Nodejs, sería mejor solución y más rápida,en este caso yo puedo elegir en que desarrollar, ya que el único requisito es usar la DB en SQL Server.

Cualquier idea es super bienvenida.

De antemano muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Para obtener los datos que devuelve un SP de sql server y capturarlos en php, necesito alguna librería o algo adicional?

***Primero deberias configurar tu php y el sqlserver para que interactuen...en internet hay muchos tutorialed que te podrian servir....de igual forma lo mas importante o entre los mas importantes tenemos los siguientes:***

***1- Descargar SQLSRV32.exe (copiar: php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll, php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll) en la ruta: C:\XAMPP\PHP\EXT\
2- Otro dato importante es instalar  SQL Server ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server, según versión 32bit o 64bit de S.O. Windows.***

¿Es posible por ejemplo traer la información de SQL Server, transformarlos en un JSON por ejemplo y luego leerlos por chartjs?, si es así, ¿Cómo podría ser?.

***En mi humilde opinion es lo que deberias hacer..JSON te podria servir si a futuro decides cambiar de manejar de base de datos y JSON es una estructura universal q te podria ayudar en este caso...citandolo como ejemplo.
Esta pagina te podria ayudar en lo que buscas: http://microbuilder.io/blog/2016/01/10/plotting-json-data-with-chart-js.html***

Espero te sirva comenta cualquier novedad y te echamos una mano.

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias bro, me sirvio a la primera!!!, en cuanto a lo de JSON me parece muy buena idea, gracias dude, saludos.